# BindParam в цикле foreach

Tags: php, mysql

```
private function SqlExecute($sql, $array = [], $param = [])
{
    if(sizeof($array) == sizeof($param))
    {
        $ini__li = $this->Connect();

        $Query = $ini__li->prepare($sql);

        $pr = [
            0 => PDO::PARAM_INT,
            1 => PDO::PARAM_STR
        ];


            $i = 0;
            foreach($array as $key => $str)
            {
                $p = $param[$i];
                $Query->bindParam($key, $str, $pr[$p]);
                $i++;
            }

        return $Query->execute();

    }else{

        return false;

    }

}
```

В массиве `$param` передаются значения 0 или 1.
В массиве `$array`, ключ маски и значение.
Некоторые запросы выполняются, а некоторые нет. Не могу найти ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PDOStatement::bindParam](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindparam.php) 
Связывает переменную PHP с именованным или неименованным параметром подготавливаемого SQL-запроса. **В отличие от PDOStatement::bindValue(), переменная привязывается по ссылке и ее значение будет вычисляться во время вызова PDOStatement::execute().**

Вы передаете переменную $str, но видно, что она передается по ссылке и когда вы меняете переменную $str она меняется и внутри запроса.
В процессе цикла вы именно ее и меняете,то есть цикл это делает автоматически.

По этой причине я заменил временную переменную цикла $str, на переменную $array[$key], эта переменная не будет менять свое значение и во время запроса (execute) будет иметь тоже значение что и в цикле

```
private function SqlExecute($sql, $array = [], $param = [])
{
    if(sizeof($array) == sizeof($param))
    {
        $ini__li = $this->Connect();

        $Query = $ini__li->prepare($sql);

        $pr = [
            0 => PDO::PARAM_INT,
            1 => PDO::PARAM_STR
        ];


            $i = 0;
            foreach($array as $key => $str)
            {
                $p = $param[$i];
                $Query->bindParam($key, $array[$key], $pr[$p]);
                $i++;
            }

        return $Query->execute();

    }else{

        return false;

    }

}
```

Comment: Черт. Работает! Почему? не вижу разницы.

Comment: поправил ответ, теперь будет видно момент где разница

Comment: еще вы можете просто использовать PDOStatement::bindValue()

Comment: Разницу в коде я то заметил, я не мог понять почему мой вариант не работает, а ваш работает. Ну вы выше уже пояснили. Спасибо.